# IIS - 403 Forbidden: Access is denied when accessing a folder published through IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, https, iis-7

We published a folder through IIS 7.0 as below and put some files in it

```
https://www.example.net/mydocs
```

If we access the files as below through browser we are able to see it

```
https://www.example.net/mydocs/client.xml
https://www.example.net/mydocs/log.jpg
```

etc..

Now we need to write a pgm to download and upload files to this folder and we coded as below

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string webAddress = null;
            try
            {
                webAddress = @"https://www.example.net/mydocs";
                webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                WebRequest serverRequest = WebRequest.Create(webAddress);
                WebResponse serverResponse;
                serverResponse = serverRequest.GetResponse();
                serverResponse.Close();

                webClient.UploadFile(webAddress + @"1.xml", "PUT", @"C:\d\1.xml");
                webClient.Dispose();
                webClient = null;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
```

But it throwing and error at `serverResponse = serverRequest.GetResponse();`

> The error is The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Also if we try to access

```
https://www.example.net/mydocs
```

through browser we are getting the error

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. when
>   accessing the folder published through iis

Comment: You need to allow Directory Browsing from IIS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to Allow Directory Browsing from IIS. Follow below steps to allow Directory Browsing.

- Open `IIS`.
- Select Your website from Left Pane.
- Double click `Directory Browsing` from Right Pane/Center Pane.
- In Right Pane under `Actions` Click `Enable`.

Comment: Followed all the following steps but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it ended up being missing windows features installed.

I can't exactly point out which features are missing as I got tired of it and installed most of them, but that for sure solved my problem (and enabling directory browsing did not).

Answer (score 1):

You Need to Enable the Directory Browsing in IIS or else you can access only files by giving full path up to the file. [Refer this link will show how](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/directorybrowse?showTreeNavigation=true)